# Creating a new array with added value from 2 fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm

Hello guys currently i have an array with some data:

```
 const data = [
      {car: 'Hyundai', price: '60.00', tax: '5.00', total: 0},
      {car: 'Honda', price: '80.00', tax: '7.00', total: 0},
      {car: 'Tesla', price: '100.00', tax: '10.00', total: 0},
  ]
```

Data set is bigger. Whats the best way to get a new array with the total(price + tax) calculated. Don't want to mutate original. So i need this back:

```
const newData = [
      {car: 'Hyundai', price: '60.00', tax: '5.00', total: 65.00},
      {car: 'Honda', price: '80.00', tax: '7.00', total: 87.00},
      {car: 'Tesla', price: '100.00', tax: '10.00', total: 110.00},
  ]
```

I have a lot more fields so I was wondering if there was a more efficient and shorter code to do it then my current solution which is forEach then on the total key, i just do data.price + data.tax.

Comment: Using a `.map()` but i think this will be slower (if efficiency is your priority use a for)

Comment: Thank you guys for the links. I guess i wasn't looking for the right question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()` to create a new array from the old array. Use ellipsis to merge the new property into a copy of the old object.

```js
const data = [
      {car: 'Hyundai', price: '60.00', tax: '5.00', total: 0},
      {car: 'Honda', price: '80.00', tax: '7.00', total: 0},
      {car: 'Tesla', price: '100.00', tax: '10.00', total: 0},
  ];
const newData = data.map((car) => ({...car, total: Number(car.price) + Number(car.tax)}));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Idk man, Array.forEach is pretty effective, but you could create an Array.map() and predefine a function. E.G:

```
function func(car) {
car.total = car.price + car.tax;
}
let newData = data.map(func);
```

Also as a tip on the code logic, might want to use let or var instead of const because inflation, price changes, and tax increase/decrease are possible.

Comment: Note the requirement: "Don't want to mutate the original".  This speaks to both your implementation and your `var/let/const` comment.